# Saving the dynamically allocated port of SSH tunnel

Tags: shell-script, ssh, openssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

There is already a [great question and answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584479/recording-the-dynamically-allocated-port-number-with-ssh-remote-port-forwarding/584505#584505), but I have a different case.

I create a tunnel with the following command:

```
$ ssh -N -R 0:192.168.0.16:80 root@164.92.194.26
Allocated port 35007 for remote forward to 192.168.0.16:80
```

I am getting output about the allocated port, however, when I background the tunnel with `-f` flag, **I am having no output in `stdout/strerr`**.

Is there a way to know the port in this case, without running some scripts on a remote server or using sockets like in the [question I linked above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584479/recording-the-dynamically-allocated-port-number-with-ssh-remote-port-forwarding/584505#584505)?

Thanks!

Comment: check this solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584505

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying with the `-f` flag does indeed prevent the report that is given otherwise. Looking at the documentation (`man ssh`, search for `-f`), we can see that

> **`-f`** Requests `ssh` to go to background just before command execution.

But in the next paragraph we can read,

> If the `ExitOnForwardFailure` configuration option is set to `yes`, then a client started with `-f` will wait for all remote port forwards to be successfully established before placing itself in the background.

This implies that without this setting the command drops itself into the background immediately, and this is why it cannot report the allocated port to you.

This leads to a modified command, which does indeed report a message such as `Allocated port 1234 for remote forward to 192.168.0.16:80`:

```
ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -fN -R 0:192.168.0.16:80 root@164.92.194.26
```

However, trying to capture that in a variable quickly identifies that it's being written to *stderr* rather than *stdout*. The final solution, therefore, is this:

```
port=$(
    ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -fN -R 0:192.168.0.16:80 root@164.92.194.26 2>&1 |
    awk '/Allocated/{print $3+0}'
)
[ -n "$port" ] && echo "Port $port was allocated"
```

resulting in an output such as this:

```
Port 42655 was allocated
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that was really helpful!

Comment: (1) You could say `port=$(` *`blah blah blah`* `)  &&  echo "` *`blah blah blah`* `"`, and eliminate the (IMO, somewhat ugly) reference to `$?`.  (2) … but, either way, you’re just testing the exit status from `awk` — is that really useful?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' ah yes. That's what comes of testing code and then extending it! Test fixed