# ssh with dynamic local port forwarding

Tags: ssh, firewall

I know remote port forwarding can dynamically allocate port.

```
ssh remote -R 0:10.19.24.19:5555
```

but unfortunately, the remote server's `iptables` forbid great range of ports.

Is there anyway for ssh to dynamically allocate port locally. Something like

```
ssh remote -L 0:10.19.24.19:5555
```

but the command above always throws an error.

### edit in 2023/02/03

Here is the situation. I am developing a tool, which is able to manage multiple port forwarding. Unfortunately, for security reason, remote server has only a narrow range of port available. Server Admin will not permit to ease the striction. So I wish I can dynamically allocate local port for forwarding.

Since local forwarding doesn't support random port allocation, I decided to use shell function to generate random port number. And use `ss` to test if forward successfully.

```bash
_next_port() {
    local lower_port upper_port
    read lower_port upper_port </proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
    while true; do
        local port=$(shuf -i $lower_port-$upper_port -n 1)
        if [[ $(ss -tulpH "sport == $port") == "" ]]; then
            echo $port
        fi
    done
}
```

case close?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? What exactly are you trying to achieve? If the remote server is under your control, you should be able to configure port forwarding by simply following configuration instructions abundantly available in the internets. Adding config files from both client and server to the question might help to resolve the issue; along with actual error messages. If the remote server is NOT under your control, the only appropriate way is to use it is to ask the server admin for instructions.

Comment: @Peregrino69 here is the situation. I am developing a tool, which is able to manage multip port forwarding. Unfortunately, for security reason, remote server has only a narrow range of port available. Server Admin will not permit to ease the striction. So I wish I can dynamically allocate local port for forwarding.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.

Comment: The `-L` option provides the remote system with access to a local service. It doesn't really make any sense to select a random local port -- it wouldn't connect to anything useful!

Comment: @larsks yes, I wish it will print information that which port is forwarding. cause -R does this way.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding the `ssh` port forwarding feature. The local/remote ports are carried over the ssh channel and have very little to do with firewall controls.

Using your first example, this command creates a randomly allocated listening port on `remoteHost`. When a process on `remoteHost` connects to it, the traffic is routed *via the ssh transport through the local client* to port 5555 on the system `10.19.24.19`:

```
   ssh -R 0:10.19.24.19:5555 remoteHost
```

Note that the `remoteHost` does not need to have direct network access to `10.19.24.19` - that's the point of the remote forwarding feature.

Consequently `iptables` has no control over the access through this port, and the restriction imposed by your systems administrators that you describe as limiting the number of open available ports is of no consequence.

It would be much easier, I think, if you defined your remote port number rather than letting `ssh` choose one randomly. However, if you are set on having it defined dynamically then other answers on StackExchange such as mine here, [Saving the dynamically allocated port of SSH tunnel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/730684/100397), may help.