# ssh `ClearAllForwardings=yes` causes -L on the command line to be ignored

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Consider the following command (which is part of a script I'm writing):

```
ssh -oClearAllForwardings=yes -NL 5555:localhost:5555 foo
```

I want `ClearAllForwardings=yes` because I might have `LocalForward` options in my ssh config and I don't want these to happen within this command (if they're already being forwarded elsewhere and it'll warn about port in use which is confusing when running this script).

But it seems that `ClearAllForwardings=yes` causes ssh to completely ignore **ALL** forwards, even when given later on the command line.

I can't tell ssh to completely ignore `~/.ssh/config` because that contains the information about how to reach `foo`.

So how can I get ssh to ignore `LocalForward` from `~/.ssh/config` but still allow forwarding a specific port on the command line?

Answer (score 5):

`~/.ssh/config` is your private file, under your control. Use this fact and arrange the file like this:

```
Host foo bar
   Hostname …
   # common options here

Host foo
   # forwardings here
```

`ssh foo` will match both sections. Your script shall `ssh -L … bar`; this command will match the section with common options, but it *will not* match the section with forwardings.

Note you need `Hostname`. If your previous config did not specify one for `foo`, the implicit hostname for `ssh foo` was `foo` and now you need `Hostname foo` (so `ssh bar` connects to `foo`, not to `bar`).

---

If for any reason you don't want to edit `~/.ssh/config` (e.g. you want a solution that is fully "inside" the script), consider the following:

Your script can run `ssh -oClearAllForwardings=yes -fNMS … foo` and then it can add/remove port forwardings by communicating with the master `ssh` process by invoking `ssh -S … -O …`. See [this other answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584505/108618) for an example that adds remote forwarding (`-R`); adding local forwarding is similar, you will need like `ssh -S … -O forward -L 5555:localhost:5555 placeholder`.

Comment: Amazing! ...never knew you could do this.

Comment: Changing ssh config isn't an option here. Adding the forwarding later using controlmaster is interesting. Is `placeholder` completely ignored or could you accidentally still end up with extra forwards if you put the real hostname here?

Comment: @SystemParadox AFAIK with `-S` and without `-M`, and with sane `-O` the destination is irrelevant, yet the argument has to be there.